# How to toggle from another js file in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner in React.js.

I have toggle button that show/hide navigation layer.

And This file named `Navi.js`

If I want to put same toggle button that show/hide navigation to `Home.js`, How to I call toggle function ?

This is what I tried so far below.
Please help.

Demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/49io4

*Navi.js*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Navi = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const onToggleClick = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };
  return (
    <div className="wrap-navi">
      <button onClick={onToggleClick} className={show ? "active" : ""}>
        toggle menu
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer1 ${show ? "active" : ""}`}>toggle1 Layer</nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navi;
```

*Home.js*

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      Home
      {/* <button onClick={onToggleClick} className={show ? "active" : ""}>
        toggle menu
      </button> */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd ideally want to maintain the toggle state in a higher component in the tree which renders both your home & your navbar component, where both Home & Navbar components can get props from the parent component.

Or you can also use redux/mobx to manage your state of sibling components in a central store and subscribe to whatever data you need.

Or you can also use `context` to get it done.

Since you're learning react the first option seems easy to implement. Move your toggle state to a component which is a ancestor to both home & navbar. Find an exampl to give you a rough idea below:

```
export default function Parent(){
  // Store the state in the parent component
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false);

  // Create a callback to toggle the value of the state & pass it down the children
  const toggleNavbar = () => {
    setShowNav(currentValue => !currentValue);
  }

  return(
    <Home toggleNavbar={toggleNavbar} />
    <Navbar showNav={showNav} />
  )
}

// Home Component

export default function Home(props){
  return (
    <button onClick={props.toggleNavar}>Toggle Navbar</button>
  )
}


// Navbar Component
export default function Navbar(props){
  const showNav = props.showNav;

  return (
    <nav className={`layer1 ${showNav ? "active" : ""}`}>toggle1 Layer</nav>
  )
}
```